# solving Project Euler #305

Tags: language-agnostic

[Problem # 305](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=305)

> Let's call S the (infinite) string
>   that is made by concatenating the
>   consecutive positive integers
>   (starting from 1) written down in base
>   10.
>
> Thus, S =
>   1234567891011121314151617181920212223242...
>
> It's easy to see that any number will
>   show up an infinite number of times in
>   S.
>
> Let's call f(n) the starting position
>   of the nth occurrence of n in S. For
>   example, f(1)=1, f(5)=81, f(12)=271
>   and f(7780)=111111365.
>
> Find Summation[f(3^k)] for 1 <= k <=
>   13.

How can I go about solving this?

Comment: are you starting with a new S each time? I ask because intuitively the 3rd occurrence of 3 should be to the left of the 9th occurrence of 9, which should be to the left of the 27th occurrence of 27, etc. Thus, you should be able to pass the last state of S for a given value of 3^k to the function call for 3^(k+1) and adjust the logic of your algorithm accordingly.

Comment: If I save the state of s, the lookup into s would be time consuming too. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

Calculating S to an arbitrary size is deceivingly easy, but as you have probably already found out, not practical, it simply becomes too big .

As is common for the newer Project Euler Problems, brute force simply does not work.

That said, you can still look at S for small values of k and maybe construct a formula that will solve the problem in parts (the first few values are easy to handle in memory). Also, look at Problem 40

Note: remember the one minute rule. (most problems can be solved in a few milliseconds)

Answer (score 0):

My estimate of the running time is O(n<sup>2</sup> log n), so this brute force approach is not feasible.

Note that you are supposed to solve Project Euler problems yourself, which IMHO applies in particular to newer problems.